# Recursively hydrate all related objects in Propel

Tags: php, propel

Is there a simple way to recursively hydrate all related objects when performing a query?

Let's say I have the following tables:

```
Song
Composer
Century
```

When I do a `SongPeer::doSelectJoinAll()` only the related composers are hydrated, so if I then do something like `$song->getComposer()->getCentury()`, a new query will be performed.

I want to perform only one query to the DB so when I call `$song->getComposer()->getCentury()` within a loop on all my songs objects, it doesn't end up in n additional queries.

Hope I'm clear :)

Thanks

Comment: For a second there I thought you were hydrating with [Propel water](http://www.propelzero.com/)... lol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you using Propel 1.2 ? The one with creole ?

If so, try to implement your own `doSelectJoinAll` on SongPeer to manually add join on other table (like century).

If you are using the latest version, you just have to [explicit `joinWith` the table](http://www.propelorm.org/reference/model-criteria.html#minimizing_queries) in your query:

```
<?php
$song = SongQuery::create()
  ->joinWith('Song.Composer')
  ->joinWith('Composer.Century');
$century = $song->getComposer()->getCentury();
```

Comment: Wow, that looks just awesome. Unfortunaly I'm stuck with Propel 1.3 (and the old criteria syntax), you know if the above is still possible in version 1.3?

Comment: The custom `doSelectJoinAll` seems to be ok in 1.3: http://trac.propelorm.org/wiki/Documentation/1.3/Relationships Unfortunaly the `joinWith` isn't ..

Comment: Argh, I was afraid it was not the case ! I'm going to try to update to Propel 1.6 since apparently it's backward compatible and use your solution. Thanks very much for the help !

Comment: It seems that for me, the correct syntax is : 
$song = SongQuery::create()
  ->joinWith('Composer')
  ->joinWith('Composer.Century');