# Propel populateRelation one-to-many relation doesn't fill relation

Tags: php, symfony-1.4, propel

I have a problem with **populateRelation**, lets explain, that we have some Article, this Article can have tags, so we do another table article_tag, this do ArticleTag object in propel, lets find the all Articles

```
$Articles = ArticleQuery::create()->find();
```

okey so we have now all Articles, now we wanna have all of those tags for each Article, so here we go:

```
$Articles->populateRelation('ArticleTag');
```

and then is some view we do:

```
foreach($Articles as $Article) {
  // some stuff
  foreach($Article->getArticleTags() as $ArticleTag) { // this should not do query!
    // some additional stuff
  }
}
```

and when I have 1 200 articles in db, with **populateRelation** the queries going down up to 600, but should be only 2, for articles and for articles tags.

Where I do mistake?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I put [an answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10110033/recursively-hydrate-all-related-objects-in-propel/10110270#10110270) about recursively populate related objects.

You just have to [explicit `joinWith` the table](http://www.propelorm.org/reference/model-criteria.html#minimizing_queries) in your query:

```
$articles = ArticleQuery::create()->joinWith('Article.ArticleTag')->find();

// this won't perform others queries
// not sure about getArticleTags or getArticleTag
foreach($articles->getArticleTags() as $ArticleTag) { }
```